# C++ using fork() to generate 2 children

Tags: c++, operating-system, fork

Would you please check my code it's a C++ program to generate 2 children of one parent. the user should enter the num value to create a chain of process. The problem is the children pid is the same for each parent how can I make them different?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Please enter a number of process "<<endl;
    int num;
    cin>>num;

    int j;
    for(j=0; j<num; j++)
    {

        pid_t pid;

        pid = fork();

        if(pid < 0)
        {
            cout<<"Error"<<endl;
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            cout << "Parent " << getpid() << endl;
            exit(0); 
        } 
        else  {
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                wait(NULL);
                cout << " Child " << getpid() << endl;

            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Parent 27130
 Child 27322
 Child 27322
Parent 27322
 Child 31901
 Child 31901
Parent 31901
 Child 20453
Child 20453
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the expected output is.

Comment: @RSahu he wants it to print only once. He wants to see the pid of the two child processes the parent creates.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems with your code. 

In the `else`, that is the child process. You are `waiting` when this process has no child processes... so it will just skip it and print its pid twice!.

This has nothing to do with `fork` but with your for loop. `for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)`

**EDIT**
If you want it to print only once, just remove the for loop and it will print only once. 
If you only want the parent two fork two child processes then the flow should be as this:

```
pid_t pid2;
cout << "Parent " << getpid() << endl;
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) { // handle error }
else if (pid == 0) { // child process 
    cout << " Child " << getpid() << endl;
} 
else { // parent process
      pid2 = fork();
      if (pid2 == -1) { //handle error }
      else if (pid2 == 0) { //child process 
          cout << " Child " << getpid() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by Tony Tannous, here's what I think you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void childFun()
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

      cout << " Child " << getpid() << endl;
   }
}

int main(){

   cout<<"Please enter a number of process "<<endl;
   int num;
   cin>>num;

   int j;
   for(j=0; j<num; j++)
   {
      pid_t pid = fork();

      if(pid < 0) {
         cout<<"Error"<<endl;
         exit(1);
      } else if (pid > 0) {
         cout << "Parent " << getpid() << endl;
         // Continue on to create next child.
         // Don't exit.
         // exit(0); 
      } else  {
         // Do whatever the child needs to do.
         childFun();

         // Exit the child process after that
         exit(0);
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit problematic, first of all, he wants to print the pid of the two processes he wishes to spawn, then the first child create in his code another child which is another problem, although you fixed that, it still prints the child process pid twice. And there is no guarantee the parent will print its pid first... the child process might run first. Look my answer.

Comment: @TonyTannous, I hope it's clear to the OP that they can modify the code in `childFun` to do whatever they want to. Whether the child PID is printed once or 10 times can be easily controlled. Re the order in which the PIDs are printed, it's easy to control the output of the parent process before the first fork but after that, there is very little a programmer can do.

Comment: Thank you for your help.